# A video recording app that will create a timestamp and title on video

Tags: video, video-recording

[image: Photo for reference]I know the ffmpeg way to do this. The problem with that is that I don't want only a timestamp but also a title and entry number of the video and make it look a little good. The timestamp created by ffmpeg is to say the least very ugly.
I haven't however found an alternative to this. I have to record a lot of video logs for my lab projects and it's very annoying to add in date and title by myself. I would rather want it to just be displayed as a HUD on the recording by default. Sort of like the cam Mark Watney had in the martian.

I just wanna know if anything like this exists at all right now, if it doesn't I guess I'll be ok with coding one myself.

Answer (score 0):

OBS Studio supports adding all kinds of information and overlays onto videos live while they're recording/streaming.  You should check it out and browse the available addons/extensions it has.

Also, if it's acceptable to add the overlays after the fact, I know that various video editors like shotcut (available as a snap) have effects and overlays for things like timestamps that can be added to a video, at which point you would just re-export it after adding the info you want.